# How is translation granule set in ARMv8-A processors?

Tags: arm

ARMv8-A supports three different translation granules, viz. 4K, 16K, 64K. However the programmer's guide doesn't speak how this is set. What field of which register controls the granule setting? Can anyone point me to the relevant part of the documentation?

Comment: Long time ago since I read it, but it is in the bit field description of the MMU table entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does TTBCR affect low addresses in ARMv8-A?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353540/how-does-ttbcr-affect-low-addresses-in-armv8-a)

Comment: You don't want the programmers' guide in the first instance, you want the ARM ARM, as in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

TCR_ELx.TG0 is the register you're looking for. See ARM DDI 0487C, 'System registers relevant to MMU operation'